# Sum of the series where exponents are in geometric progression

Tags: summation, geometric-series

Consider the following series: $x^2, x^4, x^8, \dots, x^{2^n}$

Since the series grows very very quickly, the total sum is dominated by the last term and is less than $2 \cdot x^{2^n}$.

Is there a way to compute the exact sum?

Comment: I do not think you could have a closed form expression for the **exact** sum. But good approximations, I suppose.

Comment: @Peter, I said that the exponents: 2, 4, 8, ..., 2^n are in geometric series. The series itself is not geometric.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.